# Regex matches only first Pattern and not subsequent Patterns

Tags: regex, eclipse, replace

In the sample below:

```
MARY    2.629    3,991,060  1
PATRICIA    1.073    1,628,911  2
LINDA   1.035    1,571,224  3
BARBARA 0.98     1,487,729  4
ELIZABETH   0.937    1,422,451  5
```

In this sample I want to select the characters other than the names and remove them.
In Eclipse, using Find and Replace with Regex,
 Find : `([0-9,\.\s\n]*)$`
Replace: `\n`

It just finds the matching characters in first line, `2.629    3,991,060  1`

And not in other lines.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it should have worked!also no need of `\n` because `\s` contains it

Comment: Anirudh is right. It should work. See this fiddle: http://www.debuggex.com/r/qQOURnA-S4sJqIjo/0

Note: `\n` was removed, the `m`-flag is set.

Comment: Did you select the whole sample before running the Find/Replace?

Comment: @Jerry I ran the find and replace on the file that contains the sample in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Use `(\d|\.|,|\s)+` in find expression and `\n` in the replace expression of Eclipse to achieve what you want. It will replace all the characters that occur after the initial text characters.